# Ansible conditional betwen variables

Tags: ansible

I have to check whether source and target are not the same directories and if they are not to change the name:

```
#Renaming bamboo-home folder
- name: Get {{ bamboo_home_symlink }} symlink target
  stat:
    path: "{{ bamboo_home_symlink }}"
  register: symlinkhome_target
  tags:
    - upgrade

- name: change name of folder to be {{ bamboo_home }}
  shell: mv '{{ symlinkhome_target.stat.lnk_source }}' '{{ bamboo_home }}'
  when: symlinkhome_target.stat.lnk_source is not {{ bamboo_home }}
  tags:
    - upgrade
```

Unfortunately I have got following error:

```
19:02:31 TASK [change name of folder to be /usr/data/atlassian/bamboo-8.1.2-home] *******
19:02:31 task path: /opt/data/jenkins/workspace/Team Infrastructure Services and Tools/Bamboo/Bamboo Dev/Bamboo-dev install/roles/bamboo/tasks/main.yml:146
19:02:31 [WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating
19:02:31 delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: symlinkhome_target.stat.lnk_source is
19:02:31 not {{ bamboo_home }}
19:02:31 Read vars_file 'vars/secure-user.yml'
19:02:31 Read vars_file 'vars/dev.yml'
19:02:31 [WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating
19:02:31 delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: symlinkhome_target.stat.lnk_source is
19:02:31 not {{ bamboo_home }}
19:02:31 fatal: [server.domain.company.net]: FAILED! => {
19:02:31     "msg": "The conditional check 'symlinkhome_target.stat.lnk_source is not {{ bamboo_home }}' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: expected token 'name', got '/'. String: {% if symlinkhome_target.stat.lnk_source is not /usr/data/atlassian/bamboo-8.1.2-home %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to be in '/opt/data/jenkins/workspace/Team Infrastructure Services and Tools/Bamboo/Bamboo Dev/Bamboo-dev install/roles/bamboo/tasks/main.yml': line 146, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: change name of folder to be {{ bamboo_home }}\n  ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"
19:02:31 }
```

`symlinkhome_target` is defined. See result of stat:

```
19:02:31     "stat": {
19:02:31         "exists": true, 
19:02:31         "gid": 0, 
19:02:31         "gr_name": "root", 
19:02:31         "inode": 142127337, 

19:02:31         "lnk_source": "/opt/data/atlassian/bamboo-8.1.2-home", 
19:02:31         "lnk_target": "/usr/data/atlassian/bamboo-8.1.2-home", 
19:02:31         "mimetype": "inode/symlink", 

19:02:31     }
```

Comment: No braces `{{ }}`. Try `when: symlink.stat.lnk_source != bamboo_home`

Answer (score 1):

The warning tells you what you are doing wrong that causes the error message.

```
19:02:31 [WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating
19:02:31 delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}.
```

Additionally, you should be testing for equality (`!=`) not identity (`is not`).

```yaml
- name: change name of folder to be {{ bamboo_home }}
  shell: mv '{{ symlinkhome_target.stat.lnk_source }}' '{{ bamboo_home }}'
  when: symlinkhome_target.stat.lnk_source != bamboo_home
  tags:
    - upgrade
```